# How to read contents from a web page and then output it using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to get random text from a website. My code:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = "https://www.randomlists.com/random-words"

print(url)
request = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
request.decode("utf-8")



print(request)
```

However that outputs:

```
https://www.randomlists.com/random-words
b'<!doctype html> <html lang="en-US"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <title>Random Word Generator &mdash; Get a list of random words</title> <meta name="description" content="A word randomizer for finding quick inspiration. Generate a random list of words from 2500+ of the most common English words. Also filter by part of speech!" /> <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-words" /> <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /> <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> <meta property="og:title" content="Random Word Generator &mdash; Get a list of random words" /> <meta property="og:description" content="A word randomizer for finding quick inspiration. Generate a random list of words from 2500+ of the most common English words. Also filter by part of speech!" /> <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.randomlists.com/random-words" /> <meta property="og:site_name" content="Random Lists" /> <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.randomlists.com/img/og-image.jpg" /> <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.randomlists.com/img/og-image.jpg" /> <meta property="og:image:height" content="1200" /> <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" /> <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Playing cards randomly spread about" /> <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"> <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"> <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#000000"> <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"> <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"> <link rel="preload" data-rand_json href="/data/words.json" as="fetch"> <style>@charset "UTF-8";.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:100%}@media only screen and (min-width:500px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:calc(100% - 120px - 1rem)}}@media only screen and (min-width:700px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:calc(100% - 160px - 1rem)}}@media only screen and (min-width:900px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{max-width:calc(100% - 300px - 1rem)}}.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:100%}@media only screen and (min-width:500px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:calc(100% - 120px - 1rem)}}@media only screen and (min-width:700px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{width:calc(100% - 160px - 1rem)}}@media only screen and (min-width:900px){.Header-content,.layout-main,.main_width{max-width:calc(100% - 300px - 1rem)}}html{font-size:14px}@media only screen and (min-width:728px){html{font-size:16px}}body{background:#efefea}body,input{margin:0;font-family:Roboto;line-height:1.4em}h1,h2,h3,p{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem}h1,h2,h3{font-family:"Roboto Condensed";font-weight:400;line-height:1.1em}h1{font-size:1.8rem}h2{font-size:1.4rem}h3{font-size:1.2rem}strong{font-weight:500}.section_wide{max-width:1200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;box-sizing:border-box}.section_wide.section_gutter{box-sizing:content-box}.section_gutter{padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem;box-sizing:border-box}.button{display:-webkit-inline-box;display:inline-flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;text-align:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;background:#0e1a35;cursor:pointer;height:44px;width:48px;padding:2px;font-size:8px;line-height:1.25em;-webkit-transition:all ease .2s;transition:all ease .2s;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Arial}.button:before{font-family:icon;font-size:1.2rem;line-height:1em;margin-bottom:.4rem}.button:hover{background:#224287}.button:focus{outline-style:solid;outline-width:2px}.button--yo{background:#1985a3!important}.button--yay{background:#19a337!important}.button--yay:before{content:"\xef\x80\x8c"!important}.button--edit:before{content:"\xef\x81\x80"!important}.button--wide{width:64px}.button:disabled{background:#222;cursor:no-drop;opacity:.8}.js_notice{position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;padding:1rem;background:#a32019;color:#fff;text-align:center}.js_notice a{color:currentColor}@font-face{font-family:icon;src:url(/vendor/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.ttf?cq58c8) format("truetype"),url(/vendor/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.woff?cq58c8) format("woff"),url(/vendor/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.svg?cq58c8#icomoon) format("svg");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}.layout{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.layout-main{background:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.layout-top{margin:.5rem 0 1.5rem;display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center}.adsbygoogle--top{width:320px;min-height:50px;max-height:100px}@media only screen and (min-width:630px){.adsbygoogle--top{width:468px;height:60px;min-height:0;max-height:none}}@media only screen and (min-width:1065px){.adsbygoogle--top{width:728px;height:90px}}.adsbygoogle--side1,.adsbygoogle--side2,.layout-side{display:none}@media only screen and (min-width:500px){.layout-side{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;display:block;margin:-2rem 0 0;width:120px}.adsbygoogle--side1,.adsbygoogle--side2{display:block;width:120px;height:600px}}@media only screen and (min-width:700px){.layout-side{width:160px}.adsbygoogle--side1,.adsbygoogle--side2{width:160px;height:600px}}@media only screen and (min-width:900px){.layout-side{width:300px}.adsbygoogle--side1{width:300px;height:250px}.adsbygoogle--side2{width:300px;height:600px}}.Header{background:#182e5e;color:#fff;border-bottom:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.Header a{color:inherit}.Header-content{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;height:3rem}.Header-logo{margin-left:-1rem;margin-right:auto}.Header-logo a{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;font-size:1.5rem;line-height:1em;height:3rem;padding:0 1rem;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;position:relative;margin-left:-.2rem}.Header-logo a:before{content:\'\';background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 0 0;background-size:1.25rem 1.25rem;width:1.25rem;height:1.25rem;margin-right:.2rem}.Header-menu{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;margin-right:-1rem}.Header-menu>a{height:3rem;width:3rem;margin-left:2px}.Header-menu [href*=search]:before{content:"\xef\x80\x82"}.Header-menu [href*=browse]:before{content:"\xef\x83\x89";margin-bottom:.2rem;line-height:1.4rem}.Header-suggested{margin:0 .4rem 0 0;overflow:hidden;height:3rem;font-size:.9rem}.Header-suggested ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;display:-webkit-box;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end}.Header-suggested li{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;padding:0}.Header-suggested a{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;line-height:1em;height:3rem;padding:0 .5rem}@media only screen and (max-width:620px){.Header-suggested{display:none}}.Header-search{display:none}.Rand-header{margin:1rem 0 2rem;padding-top:1rem;display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.Rand-headline{margin:0 1rem 0 0;align-self:center}.Rand-tools1{align-self:flex-start;margin:0;white-space:nowrap;position:relative}.Rand-tools2{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;position:relative;margin:2rem 0;text-align:center}.ShareButtons:not([hidden]){display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:calc(100%);left:50%;-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%);z-index:10;padding:4px;background:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}.Rand-tools1 button:not(:first-child),.Rand-tools2 button:not(:first-child),.ShareButtons button:not(:first-child){margin-left:4px}.Rand-ad{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;margin:1rem -1rem;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center}.adsbygoogle--rand{width:300px;height:250px}@media only screen and (min-width:350px){.adsbygoogle--rand{width:336px;height:280px}}@media only screen and (min-width:1065px){.adsbygoogle--rand{width:728px;height:90px}}@media only screen and (min-width:468px){.Rand-grid{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.Rand-grid>*{width:calc(50% - 1.5rem)}}.RandOptions+.RandCopy{padding-top:1rem}.RandCopy-nav .select-nav a:after{content:","}.RandCopy-nav *{display:inline;padding:0}.RandOptions{background:rgba(1,1,1,.02);padding:1rem}.RandOptions h2{margin:0 0 1rem}.RandOptions-row{margin:0 0 1rem}.RandOptions-row input:not([type=checkbox]),.RandOptions-row select,.RandOptions-row textarea{padding:.5rem;box-sizing:border-box;min-width:140px;max-width:100%}.RandOptions-row label:first-child{display:block;margin-bottom:.1rem}.RandOptions-row input:not(:first-child),.RandOptions-row select{display:block}.RandOptions-row textarea{min-height:200px;width:100%}.RandOptions-row input[type=number]{min-width:0;width:5em}.RandOptions-row input[type=checkbox]{width:1.5rem;height:1.5rem;vertical-align:bottom}.RandOptions-helper{display:block;font-size:.7rem;line-height:1.1em;margin-top:.1rem}[data-action=rerun]:before{content:"\xef\x81\xb4"}[data-action=options]:before{content:"\xef\x80\x93"}[data-action=share]:before{content:"\xef\x87\xa0"}[data-share=copy]:before{content:"\xef\x83\x85"}[data-share=facebook]:before{content:"\xef\x82\x9a"}[data-share=twitter]:before{content:"\xef\x82\x99"}[data-share=reddit]:before{content:"\xef\x8a\x81"}.Rand-stage-loading{width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:12px;text-indent:.8em;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:1em;background:transparent url(/img/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% .5rem;padding:2rem 1rem 1rem}.Rand-stage--no_images{text-align:left!important}.Rand-stage--no_images .img,.Rand-stage--no_images img{display:none!important}.Rand-stage--highlight,.RandOptions--highlight{background:rgba(1,1,1,.04)!important}.Rand-stage{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;margin:0;background:rgba(1,1,1,.02);padding:1rem .5rem 1rem 0}.Rand-stage ol,.Rand-stage ul{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}.Rand-stage li{position:relative;margin:0 0 .5rem;padding:.5rem 1rem;box-sizing:border-box;word-break:break-word;min-width:20%}@media only screen and (min-width:900px){.Rand-stage li{min-width:10%}}.Rand-stage ol{counter-reset:li;padding-left:.5rem}.Rand-stage ol>li{position:relative}.Rand-stage ol>li:before{counter-increment:li;content:counter(li);position:absolute;right:calc(100% - .8rem + .5ex);top:calc(.5rem + .5em);font-size:.8rem;line-height:1em;font-family:monospace;opacity:.5;text-align:right;white-space:nowrap}.Rand-stage img{max-width:100%;height:auto}.Rand-stage>ol>li img{display:inline-block;margin:0 0 4px}.Rand-stage>ol>li a.biglink{display:block;position:relative;padding:0 1rem 0 0;text-decoration:none}.Rand-stage>ol>li a.biglink:after{content:"\xef\x82\x8e";font-family:icon;position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;font-size:1rem;color:#000;-webkit-transition:opacity .3s ease,color .3s ease;transition:opacity .3s ease,color .3s ease;opacity:.75}.Rand-stage>ol>li a.biglink:hover:after{color:#0e1a35;opacity:1}span.rand_large,span.rand_medium,span.rand_small{display:block}.rand_huge{font-size:2.5rem;line-height:1.1em}.rand_large{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:1.25em}.rand_medium{font-size:1rem;color:#000}.rand_small{font-size:.8rem;color:#999}.monospace{font-family:monospace}</style> <link rel="preload" href="/css/defer.css?v=1575659034" as="style" onload="this.rel=\'stylesheet\'"> <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%2BCondensed%7CRoboto%3A400%2C500&display=swap" as="style" onload="this.rel=\'stylesheet\'"> <script> (function(){ const re = new RegExp("items=[^\\&]"); if(re.test(location.search)){ var style = document.createElement("style"); document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(style); style.innerHTML = ".adsbygoogle{display:none !important;height:0 !important;width:0 !important;}"; } }()); </script> <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({ google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5711305288167877", enable_page_level_ads: true }); </script> <script src="/js/defer.js?v=1575659071" defer></script> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-40634703-1"></script> <script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag(\'js\', new Date()); gtag(\'config\', \'UA-40634703-1\'); </script> </head> <body> <header class="Header"> <div class="section_wide"> <div class="Header-content section_gutter"> <div class="Header-logo"> <a href="/">Random Lists</a> </div> <nav class="Header-suggested"> <ul> <li><a href="/nouns">Nouns</a></li> <li><a href="/pictionary-words">Pictionary</a></li> <li><a href="/random-verbs">Verbs</a></li> <li><a href="/random-vocabulary-words">Vocabulary Words</a></li> <li><a href="/compound-words">Compound Words</a></li> </ul> </nav> <div class="Header-menu"> <a href="/search" class="button">Search</a> <a href="/#browse" class="button">Menu</a> </div> <div class="Header-search"> <form method="get" action="/search"> <div class="Header-search_flex"> <input type="text" name="q" required placeholder="Search&hellip;"> <button class="button"><span>Search</span></button> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </header> <div class="layout section_wide"> <div class="layout-main"> <div class="layout-top"> <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle--top" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5711305288167877" data-ad-slot="3781211666"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> </div> <main class="layout-part3 section_gutter"> <article> <div class="Rand-header"> <h1 class="Rand-headline">Random word generator:</h1> <aside class="Rand-tools1"> <button data-action="rerun" class="button">Rerun</button><button data-action="options" class="button">Options</button> </aside> </div> <div class="Rand-stage"> <div class="Rand-stage-loading"> Loading&hellip; </div> </div> <aside class="Rand-tools2"> <button data-action="rerun" class="button">Rerun</button><button data-action="options" class="button">Options</button> <button data-action="share" id="Rand-ShareButtonsLabel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Rand-ShareButtons" class="button">Share</button> <div class="ShareButtons" id="Rand-ShareButtons" aria-labelledby="Rand-ShareButtonsLabel" hidden> <button data-share="copy" class="button">Copy URL</button> <button data-share="facebook" class="button">Facebook</button> <button data-share="twitter" class="button">Twitter</button> <button data-share="reddit" class="button">Reddit</button> </div> </aside> <aside class="Rand-ad"> <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle--rand" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5711305288167877" data-ad-slot="1928302466"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> </aside> <div class="Rand-grid"> <aside class="RandOptions"> <h2>Edit Settings</h2> <form action="#" id="rand_options"> <p class="RandOptions-row"> <label for="rand_jumper">Dataset</label> <select id="rand_jumper"></select> </p> <p class="RandOptions-row"> <label for="rand_options_qty">Quantity</label> <input id="rand_options_qty" type="number" name="qty" value="12"> </p> <p class="RandOptions-row"> <input type="checkbox" name="dup" id="rand_options_dup"> <label for="rand_options_dup">Duplicates</label> </p> </form> <p><button data-action="rerun" class="button">Rerun</button></p> </aside> <div class="RandCopy"> <h2>Random Word Generator</h2> <p>Supposedly there are over one million words in the English Language. We trimmed some fat to take away really odd words and determiners. Then we grabbed the most popular words and built this word randomizer. Just keep clicking generate&mdash;chances are you won\'t find a repeat!</p> <h3>Random Word Games</h3> <p>As an exercise for English students, generate a list of ten random words and have the student write a story that incorporates those words in the order they\'re generated.</p> <p>You could also take the hard work out of playing MadLibs but for that you\'ll need to separate out the parts of speech. There\'s generators for each one, just jump over using the options below.</p> <div class="RandCopy-nav"> Also try: <nav class="select-nav"> <a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-words">Words</a> <ul> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-adjectives">Adjectives</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-adverbs">Adverbs</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/compound-words">Compound Words</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/nouns">Nouns</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-prepositions">Prepositions</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/spanish-words">Spanish Words</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-verbs">Verbs</a></li> <li><a href="https://www.randomlists.com/random-vocabulary-words">Vocabulary Words</a></li> </ul> </nav> or just <a href="/list-randomizer">create your own list</a>. </div> </div> </div> </article> <div id="rand-image-preload"></div> <script>const rand = "words";</script> <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https:\\/\\/schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"Random Lists","item":"https:\\/\\/www.randomlists.com\\/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"Words","item":"https:\\/\\/www.randomlists.com\\/random-words"}]}</script> </main> <div class="layout-prefooter"> <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle--prefooter" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5711305288167877" data-ad-slot="3781211666"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> </div> <footer class="footer section_gutter"> <nav> <ul> <li><a href="/">Home</a></li> <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li> <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li> <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li> <li><a href="/list-randomizer">Randomize your custom list</a></li> <li class="footer-sitemap"><a href="/all">Sitemap</a></li> </ul> </nav> <p class="disclosure">This site is offered as is to those who visit it. We make no guarantees regarding its services. Just enjoy yourself.</p> </footer> </div> <div class="layout-side"> <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle--side1" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5711305288167877" data-ad-slot="2304478467"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle--side2" style="display:inline-block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5711305288167877" data-ad-slot="2304478467"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> </div> </div> <script> const el_RS=document.querySelector(".Rand-stage"),el_RO=document.getElementById("rand_options"),useWebP=function(){var e=document.createElement("canvas");return!(!e.getContext||!e.getContext("2d"))&&0==e.toDataURL("image/webp").indexOf("data:image/webp")}();function randomiseNumbers(e,t,n,r){e=parseInt(e),t=parseInt(t),n=parseInt(n);var o=t-e+1,a=new Array;if(r){for(var i=0;i<n;i++)a[i]=e+Math.floor(Math.random()*o);return a}var s=1;for(i=0;i<o;i++)s=(n-a.length)/(o-i),Math.random()<=s&&a.push(i+e);return randomise(a,n,r)}function randomise(e,t,n){if(Array.isArray(e)||(e=e.split("")),e.shuffle(),n){for(var r=new Array,o=0;o<t;o++)r[o]=e[Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length)];return r}return t>0&&t<e.length?e.slice(0,t):e}Array.prototype.shuffle=function(){var e,t,n=this.length;if(0!=n)for(;--n;)e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(n+1)),t=this[n],this[n]=this[e],this[e]=t};const rand_json=function(){var e=[];const t=document.head.querySelectorAll("[data-rand_json]");for(var n=t.length-1;n>=0;n--)e.unshift(t[n].getAttribute("href"));return e}();function getRandOptions(){if(!el_RO)return;var e={};const t=el_RO.querySelectorAll("[name]");for(var n=t.length-1;n>=0;n--){const r=t[n].getAttribute("name"),o=t[n].getAttribute("id"),a=document.getElementById(o);"checkbox"===t[n].type?e[r]=a.checked:e[r]=a.value}return e}function strip(e){return(new DOMParser).parseFromString(e,"text/html").body.textContent||""}function triggerEvent(e,t){t=void 0===t?window:t;var n=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");n.initEvent(e,!1,!0),t.dispatchEvent(n)}function getJSON(e,t){var n=new XMLHttpRequest;n.open("GET",e,!0),n.onload=function(){if(n.status>=200&&n.status<400){const e=JSON.parse(n.responseText);t(e)}},n.send()}function copyText(e){var t=document.createElement("input");t.setAttribute("style","opacity:0;position:absolute;"),t.value=e,document.body.appendChild(t),t.select(),document.execCommand("copy"),t.parentNode.removeChild(t)}if(function(){if(!el_RO)return;var e,t=(e||document.location.search).replace(/(^\\?)/,"").split("&").map(function(e){return this[(e=e.split("="))[0]]=e[1],this}.bind({}))[0];const n=el_RO.querySelectorAll("[name]");for(var r=n.length-1;r>=0;r--){var o=n[r].getAttribute("name");if(!t[o])return;if("checkbox"===n[r].type){const e=t[o]&&"false"!=t[o];n[r].checked=e}else{var a=decodeURIComponent(t[o]).replace(/\\+/g," ");n[r].value=strip(a)}}}(),el_RS){const e=function(){var e=document.getElementById("style_rand_stage");e?e.innerHTML="":((e=document.createElement("style")).setAttribute("id","style_rand_stage"),document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e));var t=document.querySelector(".Rand-stage > ol");if(t){var n=t.offsetWidth,r=function(e,t,n){var r=document.querySelectorAll(e);if(0!=r.length){for(var o=0,a=0;a<r.length;a++){var i=r[a].offsetWidth;i>o&&(o=i)}var s=1/Math.floor(t/o);s=100*(s<1?s:1),n.innerHTML+=e+"{min-width:"+s+"%;}"}};r(".Rand-stage > ol > li",n,e),r(".Rand-stage > ol ol > li",n,e)}};window.addEventListener("rand_ran",e),window.addEventListener("resize",e),window.addEventListener("fonts_loaded",e)}!function(){const e=document.head.querySelectorAll("[as=style]");for(var t=e.length-1;t>=0;t--)e[t].setAttribute("rel","stylesheet")}();var runRand=function(){var a=getRandOptions();getJSON(rand_json,function(n){var e=n.data||n.RandL.items,s=!!(n&&n.RandL&&n.RandL.meta&&n.RandL.meta.img)&&n.RandL.meta.img;s.local&&s.suffix&&useWebP&&(".png"!=s.suffix&&".jpg"!=s.suffix||(s.suffix=".webp"));var r=function(a,n){return a};s&&(r=function(a,n){var e=n.prefix;return n.local?n.merge_underscores?e+=a.replace(/\\W+/g,"_").toLowerCase():e+=a.replace(/\\W/g,"_").toLowerCase():e+=a,n.suffix&&(e+=n.suffix),e});for(var i=randomiseNumbers(0,e.length-1,a.qty,a.dup),l="",t=0;t<i.length;t++){var m="";if("string"==typeof e[i[t]]||e[i[t]]instanceof String)s&&n.RandL.meta.img.local?(m+="<span class=\'img\'><img src=\'"+r(e[i[t]],s)+"\' alt=\'\'></span>",m+="<span class=\'rand_medium\'>"+e[i[t]]+"</span>"):m+="<span class=\'rand_large\'>"+e[i[t]]+"</span>";else{var d=!1;if(e[i[t]].img?(m+="<span class=\'img\'><img src=\'"+r(e[i[t]].img,s)+"\' alt=\'\'></span>",d=!0):s&&n.RandL.meta.img.local&&(m+="<span class=\'img\'><img src=\'"+r(e[i[t]].name,s)+"\' alt=\'\'></span>",d=!0),e[i[t]].yt&&(m+="<div class=\'yt\'><iframe width=\'420\' height=\'315\' src=\'//www.youtube.com/embed/"+e[i[t]].yt+"\' frameborder=\'0\' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>",d=!0),e[i[t]].name)m+="<span class=\'"+(d?"rand_medium":"rand_large")+"\'>"+e[i[t]].name+"</span>";if(e[i[t]].detail)m+="<span class=\'"+(d?"rand_small":"rand_medium")+"\'>"+e[i[t]].detail+"</span>";e[i[t]].url&&(m="<a class=\'biglink\' href=\'"+e[i[t]].url+"\' target=\'_blank\'>"+m+"</a>")}l+="<li>"+m+"</li>"}el_RS.innerHTML="<ol>"+l+"</ol>",triggerEvent("rand_ran")})};runRand(); </script> <noscript> <div class="js_notice">You need to enable JavaScript. See: <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">How to enable JavaScript in your browser</a></div> </noscript> </body> </html>'
```

This is html. I've also tried:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = "https://www.randomlists.com/random-words"

print(url)
request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

word = request.read()
word.decode("utf-8")


print(word)
```

but it outputs the same. **How do I read the contents of a web page and then output it?**

Example of desired output:

```
machine
somber
fancy
bitter
limping
lip
clear
worry
belief
arm
jam
board
```

The web page has 12 randomly generated words at a time.

Comment: The HTML *is* the contents of the webpage. Are you looking for something specific from the page?

Comment: Yes @rdas . I am looking to read the text on the webpage.

Comment: Please include an example of the desired output

Comment: That IS the content of the page. It's HTML. If you're looking for the content of the page as it appears on the browser, you need to strip out the HTML. Check out the `get_text()` function from the `BeautifulSoup` library. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Check out [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn how to parse the html and pull the part of it that you want. Note that if the text you want is generated via javascript, then using just urllib won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it often happens with modern web applications, the app that you use has an undocumented JSON api which might be better suited for reading by an external application than the HTML page designed to be rendered by a browser.

If you checked the requests that the browser issues when loading the page you may have noticed that the browser issues request for the url `https://www.randomlists.com/data/words.json`. This returns the whole list of words used by the app as a json array.

The code below fetches this url and chooses the words at random using Python random number functions.

```python
import json
import random
import urllib.request

NOUT = 15
URL = "https://www.randomlists.com/data/words.json"
request_data = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
json_data = json.loads(request_data)
nwords = len(json_data["data"])
idxs = random.choices(range(nwords), k=NOUT)
random_words = [json_data["data"][i] for i in idxs]

for word in random_words:
    print(word)
```

Every time you run this code it would output a list of `NOUT` different words.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the html code, either manually or using a library that does it for you as BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/